# Moving from build to local build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm moving my phonegap app from phonegap build to non build and i'm struggling to setup the plugins. The code all worked with build so I'd like to keep as much of it as possible.

I'm trying to run the [Android App Billing](https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/tree/master/v3) plugin. I git cloned it to the directory then added it with:

```
Toms-Mac-mini:Tagi tombeech$ phonegap local plugin add AndroidInAppBilling/v3/
[phonegap] adding the plugin: AndroidInAppBilling/v3/
[phonegap] successfully added the plugin
```

Then I added the JS file, referenced it and loaded it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/inappbilling.js"></script>
```

However, my code isn't initializing on ready. I've looked at the android logcat and i'm getting:

```
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367): Uncaught exception from plugin
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1096)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1190)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:351)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling.InAppBillingPlugin.init(InAppBillingPlugin.java:122)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling.InAppBillingPlugin.execute(InAppBillingPlugin.java:67)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-15 16:43:11.724: E/PluginManager(1367):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Those errors don't look too great and i'm stuck as to what to do next. None of the plugins really seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up billing_key for your application in res/values.
More information in https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/blob/master/v3/README.md